# Select case when, combine more than 1 condition taking into account multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets look at the examplary simplified tables I have:

```
Classes table:

class_id
1
2
3

Students table:

id, class_id, name,   sex
1,  1,        John,   M
2,  1,        Mike,   M
3,  3,        Rob,    M
4,  2,        Kate,   F
5,  2,        Sophie, F
6,  2,        Laura,  F
7,  3,        Julia,  F
```

I want to have a column where will be stated if class is male, female or mixed

I tried like this but it doesn't work, looks like checking only first student in the class and assigns its value to result. Class '3' should be 'mixed'

```
select class_id,
case when s.sex = 'M' then 'Male'
when s.sex = 'F' then 'Female'
when s.sex = 'F' and s.sex = 'M' then 'Mixed'
end as class_type
    from class c
    join students as s on s.class_id = c.class_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT C.class_id, 
       (CASE WHEN MIN(S.SEX) <> MAX(S.SEX) THEN 'MIXED' ELSE CAST(MIN(S.SEX) AS text) END) AS class_type
FROM Classes C INNER JOIN
     Students S
     ON S.class_id = C.class_id
GROUP BY C.class_id;
```

However, `JOIN` with `Classes` is redundant here if you want only  `class_id` other than more information from `Classes` table.

Comment: The `join` to `classes` is unnecessary.

Comment: What about if instead of F and M I have '1' and '2' ? It returns me an error invalid input syntax for integer: "MIXED" , tried max(varchar(s.sex)) but doesn't work

Comment: @sh4rkyy. . . If you have a `INT` value instead then do conversation with `MIN(S.SEX)`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it

Comment: @sh4rkyy. . . Then look at my comment under question.

Comment: Sorry missed this one, I'm using postgresql

Comment: @sh4rkyy. . . Use `CAST()` i.e. `CAST(MIN(S.SEX) AS text)` or you can also do : `MIN(S.SEX)::text`